# Open New Tab and Close the Current Tab

Tags: javascript, tabs

Is there any easy work around to close the current tab and open a new tab by javascript?

Comment: Open the URL in the current tab

Comment: @Tushar Will that have a back button? I need to disable the back button in browser.

Answer (score 5):

Try below :

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');window.setTimeout(function(){this.close();},1000)
```

Comment: I get `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.`

Answer (score 5):

you can use `location.replace` for same goal:

```js
window.location.replace('https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
this.close();
```

window.open will open the new tab according to the user browser settings only. Sorry that I didn't find any way to open an url in new tab if the user's browser settings wont allow you to.

In browser settings, set it to allow popups and then try. This will work.

Instead, to disable back button you can use options given in this page

http://www.irt.org/script/311.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript this will explain you further about we have no option to open new tab unless the browser settings allow us to.

Answer (score 1):

```
var win = window.open('/Employees/GetAttendenceDataBySelectedData/?attendDateString=' + $("#AttendDate").val() + ', "_blank');

window.top.close();
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of your solution, don't just post. Also, try to restructure your answer on a more visually compact way.